# ASP.net C# access css pseudo elements from code behind

Tags: html, css, asp.net

On an asp control I have an html element that has a css style applied to it using a `::before` pseudo element.
 
Sometimes depending on some variables that are determined in the code behind of the control I don't want that `::before` style to be applied.

How can I accomplish this, since the `::before` element is not an actual element on the page?

Thanks

Comment: Apply a different CSS clss ( which does not have the :before part) based on this variable value ?

Comment: Thats a good idea. 
If there is no direct way to do it, I guess I will make a css tag which will use :before and and another with identical styles that doesn't have a :before element.